# When are verbal commands issued to conjured animals?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions, summoning

I’m losing a lot of actions with my (Druid) conjured animals, especially when there are lots of actions, and the battle is fluid.

So many things change during a turn, so that my verbal command, issued during my turn, has typically long since been obsoleted or is far less optimal. For example, an invisible enemy is exposed, or a charmed target needs to be hit, or innumerable other circumstances arise.

**Can I issue the “verbal command” on the conjured animals' turn?  Or does the verbal command need to be issued on my turn?**

(And is the answer an “official” answer? The DM might overrule it anyways.)

Otherwise it’s like tossing the dice and hoping my command is still applicable at the time of their action.

Being a concentration spell makes it worse as it limits my actions enough as it is without the added pain of losing a turn as the animals do something not what needed to be done.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: What kind of commands are you giving that they're unable to follow by the time their turn arrives? There is a definite answer to this question under the rules, but I'd like to know the actual problem you're having.

Answer (score 5):

### You can only speak at all on your turn.

From the section titled ["Other Activity on Your Turn"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#YourTurn):

> You can communicate however you are able, through brief utterances and gestures, as you take your turn.

That said, I'm not sure what kind of commands you're giving, but in general they should be able to do something useful no matter how the situation changes before their turn. If the command is "protect that guy", then unless the guy teleports away or gets disintegrated immediately after that, they're going to be able to protect him somehow. (Unless nobody is threatening that guy, and then the fight's over, right?) If it's "attack the orcs" then they should pick an orc and attack until they run out of orcs.

Also remember that even with *no* orders, they will defend themselves against hostile creatures.

Comment: The OP has given some good examples of what commands may need to change round by round.

Comment: This is a severe and as far as I can tell unintended nerf to the spell, if the summoned creatures last for 2 fights and roll higher than the caster in fight 2 they do nothing on turn 1 because they haven't been given a command?

Comment: @SeriousBri First, you can give them a command immediately after summoning them, and they'll act on it when their turn comes up. Second, if you're in combat, they should never "do nothing". They will defend themselves by instinct. You only need to give commands to get them to do something more specific.

Comment: @Pureferret No, there are no examples of commands.

Comment: @SeriousBri Reading your comment again, I'm not sure I'm addressing your concern. "If the summoned creatures last for 2 fights and roll higher than the caster in fight 2"--are you talking a situation where they're summoned before the start of combat?

Comment: @MarkWells I guess I'm reading into the implied commands in this: *For example, an invisible enemy is exposed, or a charmed target needs to be hit, or innumerable other circumstances arise.*

Comment: @Pureferret What I'm trying to get to is table protocol. Is a command "Kill the wizards", or "Move to grid position C11, use your Bite attack against the wizard on the right, and then your Claw attack against the wizard on the left"?

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback.    I am giving them a command the turn they are summoned.     And I know they’ll defend themselves.   Defending themselves isn’t the main issue as the enemies are generally focussing on the players.....     but the fight I was involved with had 2 enemy casters , 1 able to become ethereal and charm (a succubus) and one lightning bolting wizard with greater invis.       Trying to desperately redirect my animals to hit and break the charm on (our)  PC murdering us..

Comment: I never have an issue with issuing “general” commands.  “Attack the drow.” Or “attack Apollo’s” (the charmed PC) .    It was with being able to redirect them in a changing environment,   (And yes to make it worse they went before me)  especially with charm, monsters going ethereal, PC charmed.   But if I’m limited to placing commands in my turn?  Then it’s a huge disadvantage I see only getting worse as we level up and more complicated spell effects hit the battlefield.

Comment: Yes I was referring to when they are summoned before combat, or in one combat which ends but since they last an hour they could still be up for the next fight. If they win initiative for example they won't even know there is a threat to defend themselves from. I actually think by the rules this may be the right answer, but I really hate it.

Comment: @SeriousBri I'd suggest giving them a command when you're not in combat, like "stay close and defend me" or "guard the camp" or "scout ahead for danger".